# How to sort a particular page number in Spring Data JPA?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this paging problem where when I try to sort a table by **field header** on a particular **page number**, `PageRequest.of(page-1, 10, sort)` is sorting the entire table, not on a particular page. Thus, what record is returned in that page is different from the previous record before sorting.

Code:

```
@Override
public Page<User> getPageAndSort(String field, String direction, int page) {

    Sort sort = direction.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name())
            ? Sort.by(field).ascending()
            : Sort.by(field).descending();

    Pageable pageable = PageRequest.of(page-1, 10, sort);

    return userRepo.findAll(pageable);
}
```

For example. I want to sort only in page 1 by id. Returning a sorted record from page 1. The rest of the pages or entire records shouldn't
be affected.

Thank you.

Edit:

I have a workaround in this problem. After getting a page from:

`Page<User> page = userService.findPage(currentPage);`

I get the `page.getContent()` List and then pass to method sortList:

```
userService.sortList(new ArrayList<>(page.getContent()), field, sortDir)
```

sort implementation:

```
public ArrayList<User> sortList(ArrayList<User> users, String field, String direction) {
    users.sort((User user1, User user2) -> {

        try {
            Field field1 = user1.getClass().getDeclaredField(field);
            field1.setAccessible(true);
            Object object1 = field1.get(user1);

            Field field2 = user2.getClass().getDeclaredField(field);
            field2.setAccessible(true);
            Object object2 = field2.get(user2);

            int result = 0;

            if (isInt(object1.toString())) {
                result = Integer.parseInt(object1.toString()) - Integer.parseInt(object2.toString());
            } else {
                result = object1.toString().compareToIgnoreCase(object2.toString());
            }

            if (result > 0) {
                return direction.equalsIgnoreCase("asc") ? 1 : -1;
            }

            if (result < 0) {
                return direction.equalsIgnoreCase("asc") ? -1 : 1;
            }

            return 0;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.error(e.toString());
            return 0;
        }
    });

    return users;
}
```

With this work around. I successfully sorted a particular page by its column header without affecting the rest of pages. But it's not standard though as it doesn't use `PageRequest.of()` from Spring Data JPA and I recommend testing the code and review it thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

I think an if condition could solve the problem. Create Pageable instance with respect to the condition.

```
@Override
public Page<User> getPageAndSort(String field, String direction, int page) {

    Sort sort = direction.equalsIgnoreCase(Sort.Direction.ASC.name())
            ? Sort.by(field).ascending()
            : Sort.by(field).descending();

    Pageable pageable = (page == 1)?PageRequest.of(page-1, 10, sort)
    :PageRequest.of(page-1, 10);

    return userRepo.findAll(pageable);
}
```

References : [https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting#:~:text=We%20can%20create%20a%20PageRequest%20object%20by%20passing,%280%2C%202%29%3B%20Pageable%20secondPageWithFiveElements%20%3D%20PageRequest.of%20%281%2C%205%29%3B](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-jpa-pagination-sorting#:%7E:text=We%20can%20create%20a%20PageRequest%20object%20by%20passing,%280%2C%202%29%3B%20Pageable%20secondPageWithFiveElements%20%3D%20PageRequest.of%20%281%2C%205%29%3B)

I think this helps.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is an easy way to make this kind of sorting in the database and since you are dealing with a single page which is memory anyway since you render it to the UI, I would just sort it in memory.

Alternatively you can go with a custom SQL statement structured like this:

```sql
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM WHATEVER
    ORDER BY -- sort clause defining the pagination
    OFFSET ... LIMIT ... -- note that this clause is database dependent.
) ORDER BY -- your sort criteria within the page goes here
```

You'll have to construct this SQL statement programmatically, so you can't use Spring Datas special features like annotated queries or query derivation.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure, I got your question, but if you want a certain sorted page, the db should definitely create the query plan, sort all the data and return you a certain offset (Page) of the sorted data.
It's impossible to get a sorted page without sorting the whole data.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you want to sort data only on a given page, this is difficult to manage with database query which probably will sort whole data and would give you nth page.

I would suggest to do a reverse on a given page after retrieving with same order.

1. Retrieve the nth page with from database with always asc.
2. Depending on direction do a reverse if needed.

This should be faster than relying on database for sort operation.